# Is Cloudera impala support mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cloudera, impala

Impala supports direct querying of data in the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) and HBase (NoSQL database) indexes,does it support mongodb(NoSQL database)?

Answer (score 1):

According to Cloudera's official [Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh/impala.html) documentation, MongoDB isn't supported.

*Sorry but it is hard to elaborate more, simple question, simple answer!*

Comment: last night, i found "Let’s look at a real-life example of intergrating Impala with MongoDB. A company named
Stripe (web and mobile payments for developers) ran into the same issue described above.
They needed to provide reporting on their MongoDB data, but the database was not capable
of providing the quality of reporting required for their business. As an application database,
MongoDB is great, but as an analytical database, not so much, but that’s fine because it was
never designed to be one." in book <impala in action>.

Comment: Stripe created a library for this called ZeroWing (https://github.com/stripe/zerowing).  It appears that it is capable of imitating a member of a Mongo replica set and streaming oplog data directly into HBase.  Impala can then be used to query the data in HBase.